# SwiftUI: use a different environment object for each view

Tags: swiftui, swift5

In SwiftUI I have a couple of different screens. For each screen I have a ViewController, SwiftUI View and a combined EnvironmentObject. The combined EnvironmentObject has two observable classes, one is ViewModel and the other is Interactor.

How would I use an Interactor and a ViewModel for each SwiftUI view without using a ViewController like I am doing? And where there is a different EnvironmentObject for each View.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModel1: ObservableObject {
    //Published data for view
    @Published var text: String

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}


class Interactor1<VC: UIViewController>: ObservableObject {

    let vc: VC
    let viewModel: ViewModel1?

    init(vc: VC, viewModel: ViewModel1?) {
        self.vc = vc
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    func buttonClicked() {
        //present second ViewController by using vc.present...
    }
}


class CombinedObject<VC: UIViewController>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var interactor: Interactor1<VC>
    @Published var viewModel: ViewModel1

    var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    var anyCancellable2: AnyCancellable? = nil

    init(vc: VC, index: Int) {
        viewModel = ViewModel1(text: "text1")

        interactor = Interactor1(vc: vc, viewModel: nil)
        interactor = Interactor1(vc: vc, viewModel: viewModel)

        anyCancellable = interactor.objectWillChange.sink { (_) in
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }

        anyCancellable2 = viewModel.objectWillChange.sink { (_) in
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}


class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let combinedObject = CombinedObject(vc: self, index: 0)
        let view1 = View1<ViewController1>().environmentObject(combinedObject)
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: view1)

        self.addChild(hostingController)
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}


struct View1<VC1: UIViewController>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var combinedObject: CombinedObject<VC1>

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Button(action: {
                self.combinedObject.interactor.buttonClicked()
            }, label: {
                Text(self.combinedObject.viewModel.text)
                })
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Environment objects are injected by types, so you can inject separately view model and interator, like below

```
struct View1<VC1: UIViewController>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel1
    @EnvironmentObject var iterator: Interactor1<VC1>

    ...
```

and they will be available to all subviews (both, but independently, based on declaration), for example

```
struct SubView1<VC1: UIViewController>: View { // only with view model
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel1

struct SubView2<VC1: UIViewController>: View { // only with iterator
    @EnvironmentObject var iterator: Interactor1<VC1>
```

and, finally, and required, for root view both must be injected on construction, like (scratchy)

```
View1(...)
   .environmentObject(ViewModel1(...))
   .environmentObject(Interactor1(...))
```

order does not matter, as injected by type.

Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

Comment: This means I would load the data for all the screens before showing the root view. Maybe it is not possible to do what I am trying to achieve, but this way at least doesn’t really work well because it is expensive and unnecessary to load a lot of data that might not even be needed (in the case of a user who would not go to all the views). Possibly the view could call some method to set the env data when needed? Anyway I am just a bit confused about how to set up nicely the architecture without using the vc part.

Comment: @DevB2F, Wait... haven't you do the same in combined object? I thought you just wanted to that separately... and, this is just a mechanism to set up environment, you have not to load all content at once, some can be lazy, some can be injected lately, some can be calculable, etc. It is just a possibility to set references available from everywhere in hierarchy. Everything else is under your control.